Example of a class of structures not axiomatizable in any $n$-th order logic, for finite $n$
I suppose these questions have already been asked here somewhere, but I haven't found it.

Do we know of any class of structures that is not axiomatizable in any $n$th-order logic, for finite $n$? Or are the finite-order logics sort of exhaustive in this sense?

Do we know of any class of graphs that is not axiomatizable in any $n$th-order logic, for finite $n$?

Are the two previous questions basically the same? Since I suspect that any structure is sort of encodable in a graph.



If you allow classes of structures to not be closed under isomorphism, then this is trivial (since $n$th order logic never distinguishes between isomorphic structures). So WLOG let's focus on isomorphism-closed classes of structures.
By a counting argument there will be a class $\mathbb{K}$ of countable graphs which is closed under isomorphism but is not $n$th-order axiomatizable for any $n$ (since there are continuum-many $n$th-order theories but $2^\mathfrak{c}$-many sets of countable graphs up to isomorphism). However, this doesn't give a concrete example of such a class.
We can do a bit better by considering structures which look like $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ together with an additional unary predicate which we think of as (via Godel numbering) describing a set of finite-order-logic sentences; now let $\mathbb{K}$ be the class of structures $\mathfrak{A}$ such that the theory described by $\mathfrak{A}$ is true in $\mathfrak{A}$. A la Tarski, this will do the job. But this is still quite messy.
Here's another example. Again by a counting argument, there is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that every structure is $\omega$th-order-equivalent to a structure of size $<\kappa$. Now, consider the class of structures of size $>\kappa$.
(And re: your third question the answer is essentially yes: any structure in a finitely language can be "nicely coded" by a graph, even an undirected graph! See e.g. this answer by Keith Kearnes.)
